# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity al logearte

Tags: android-studio, activity, android-glide

La aplicación se inicia sin problemas, pero cuando le doy a salir de la cuenta y me logeo de nuevo, empieza como a parpadear la pantalla, como si estuviera saltando entre activities y luego da error y se para. Lo que veo que va variando es esta línea "com.example.blindchat2.Adapter.StoryAdapter$2.onDataChange(StoryAdapter.java:119)" por lo que me da a entender que el error viene de atrás.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.blindchat2, PID: 13838
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:323)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:132)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:116)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:707)
    at com.example.blindchat2.Adapter.StoryAdapter$2.onDataChange(StoryAdapter.java:119)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:183)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Este código es de la manera que salgo de la cuenta, sospecho que puede venir de aquí el problema.

```
      private void userInfo(final ViewHolder viewHolder, String userid, final int pos){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(viewHolder.story_photo); //Marca error en esta línea
            if (pos != 0) {
                Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(viewHolder.story_photo_seen);
                viewHolder.story_username.setText(user.getUsername());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Dejo también el ViewHolder por si es de ayuda

```
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.add_story_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new StoryAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.story_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new StoryAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

Lo que aparece en el Logcat

```
[emulator-5554]: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.blindchat2, PID: 20894
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:323)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:132)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:116)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:707)
    at com.example.blindchat2.Adapter.PostAdapter$14.onDataChange(PostAdapter.java:346)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Se queja de esta función ahora mismo:

```
 private void publisherInfo(final ImageView image_profile, final TextView username, final TextView publisher, final String userid){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users").child(userid);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            publisher.setText(user.getUsername());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: El problema es con Glide, agrega el còdigo donde lo usas

Answer (score 0):

El error se especifica aquì :

> IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed
> activity

es especifico de Glide y es relacionado al contexto usado para cargar las imagenes en alguna vista.

El contexto que debes usar si te encuentras en una Activity es `getApplicationContext()` de esta forma:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
```

si te encuentras en un Fragment debes usar getActivity() para obtener el contexto.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
```

si te encuentras en un Fragment debes usar getActivity() para obtener el contexto.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
```

pero en el caso que muestras estas usando Glide dentro de un Adapter, en este adapter debes obtener el contexto , de hecho lo recibes seguramente en la variable `mContext`, por lo tanto en este caso puedes usar simplemente:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
```

Comment: Le he añadido ese nuevo código y no hay cambios

Comment: REvisaste el LogCat? veo que usas Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()) debes usar Glide.with(getApplicationContext())

Comment: He añadido lo que aparece en el LogCat, poniendo lo que tú me dices me dice que no puede reconocer ese método, sin embargo si uso mContext.getApplicationContext() no se queja pero no soluciona el problema, porque si pongo en todos los lados el problema continúa pero la aplicación no se cierra.

Comment: Acabo de ver , donde pusiste mContext.getApplicationContext() es un Adapter verdad?

Comment: no debes usar lo mismo en todas las clases de tu aplicación, agregue varios casos en los cuales deberías usar determinado contexto.

Comment: Efectivamente, los errores que marchan siempre son en los adapter, antes solo tenía la variable mContext, como me dijiste esto antes "getApplicationContext() " lo cambié a como me dejaba a " mContext.getApplicationContext()", pero de ninguna combinación funciona